# (React Native) Huawei Location Kit - is there any way to know if network location services setting switch off?

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-location-kit

to make our apps working indoor to fetch location we need Network Location Services switch to be on

[image]

And we're using this function to detect any setting that still off
[image]

We noticed the response which is **LocationSettingsStates**, when the switch on or off is always true

[image]

Am I using wrong function to detect it??

Answer (score 1):

The class and methods mentioned in the original post are the right ones to be used for checking network location service availability.

Please refer to a partial code extracted from Huawei sample code obtained from [Github](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-location-demo/tree/master/hms-location-demo-android-studio)

```
public void checkSettings(View view) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                CheckSettingsRequest checkSettingsRequest = new CheckSettingsRequest();
                LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                checkSettingsRequest.setLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                checkSettingsRequest.setAlwaysShow(false);
                checkSettingsRequest.setNeedBle(false);
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(checkSettingsRequest.getLocationRequest())
                    .setAlwaysShow(checkSettingsRequest.isAlwaysShow())
                    .setNeedBle(checkSettingsRequest.isNeedBle());
                settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                            if (task != null && task.isSuccessful()) {
                                LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult();
                                if (response == null) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates =
                                    response.getLocationSettingsStates();

                                stringBuilder.append(",\nisLocationPresent=")
                                    .append(locationSettingsStates.isLocationPresent());
                                stringBuilder.append(",\nisLocationUsable=")
                                    .append(locationSettingsStates.isLocationUsable());
                                stringBuilder.append(",\nisNetworkLocationUsable=")
                                    .append(locationSettingsStates.isNetworkLocationUsable());
                                stringBuilder.append(",\nisNetworkLocationPresent=")
                                    .append(locationSettingsStates.isNetworkLocationPresent());
                                stringBuilder.append(",\nisHMSLocationUsable=")
                                    .append(locationSettingsStates.isHMSLocationUsable());
                                stringBuilder.append(",\nisHMSLocationPresent=")
                                    .append(locationSettingsStates.isHMSLocationPresent());
                                LocationLog.i(TAG, "checkLocationSetting onComplete:" + stringBuilder.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                            LocationLog.i(TAG, "checkLocationSetting onFailure:" + e.getMessage());
                            int statusCode = 0;
                            if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                                statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                            }
                            switch (statusCode) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                    android.util.Log.i(TAG,
                                        "Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade "
                                            + "location settings ");
                                    try {
                                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                        // result in onActivityResult().
                                        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                                            ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                            rae.startResolutionForResult(CheckSettingActivity.this, 0);
                                        }
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                        android.util.Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LocationLog.i(TAG, "checkLocationSetting exception:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

The execution results when “network location service” is turned on and off are shown below. It shows the state with true and false respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some phone, LocationSettings interface may not be able to get the exact state.

You can set the Priority to be PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY and use requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback interface to get location update.

If the network location is not enabled, you will get the error code NETWORK_LOCATION_SERVICES_DISABLED 10105.

Then it means the switch is not enabled.